# CS50, PS4 - Filter (Less) - BLUR

Tags: segmentation-fault, cs50

I have been breaking my head with BLUR and keep getting segmentation fault.

Please request someone to tell me what I am doing wrong with my code. It's super annoying and demotivating to keep getting errors after spending so much time.

For more context, I have pasted my entire code, as I wasn't sure which part of the code was causing the error. Please let me know if this makes sense. I have tried to identify 9 unique situations and then tried to work around it.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        if(((height-1)>i>0)&&((width-1)>j>0))
        {
            r = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed;
            g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
            b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(r/9);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(g/9);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(b/9);
        }
        else if((i=0)&&((width-1)>j>0))
        {
            r = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed;
            g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
            b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(r/6);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(g/6);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(b/6);
        }

        else if(((height-1)>i>0)&&(j=0))
        {
            r = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed;
            g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen;
            b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(r/6);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(g/6);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(b/6);
        }

        else if((i=(height-1))&&((width-1)>j>0))
        {
            r = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed;
            g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
            b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(r/6);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(g/6);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(b/6);
        }

        else if(((height-1)>i>0)&&(j=(width-1)))
        {
            r = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed;
            g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
            b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(r/6);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(g/6);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(b/6);
        }

        else if((i=0)&&(j=0))
        {
            r = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j].rgbtRed;
            g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen;
            b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(r/4);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(g/4);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(b/4);
        }

        else if((i=(height-1))&(j=0))
        {
            r = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed;
            g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen;
            b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(r/4);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(g/4);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(b/4);

        }

        else if((i=(height-1))&&(j=(width-1)))
        {
            r = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed;
            g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen;
            b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(r/4);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(g/4);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(b/4);
        }

        else if((i=0)&&(j=(width-1)))
        {
            r = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed;
            g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
            b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(r/4);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(g/4);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(b/4);
        }

for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < width; j++)
{
    image[i][j] = copy[i][j];
 }
}
    }
}
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please try to make a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try putting printf in the beginning of each if/else if condition and look at what prints and doesnt print. The last print before the error will show you where the segfault is originating from.